# How to align buttons to be positioned across all Android platforms?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have used grid layout to place an 8x8 grid of buttons on the screen. Since I am new to Android, I am unsure of how to make this fit all the buttons as they should be across all different Android Phones.

For example, when I have the 8x8 grid on the virtual Nexus 6, the buttons are fit perfectly. However on the Nexus 7, there is extra space between the left rows and the edge of the screen and the right rows and the edge of the right side of the screen. And then on the Nexus 4, the 7th and 8th column buttons are off of the screen.

I'm sure you understand the point I am trying to make, so if someone could help me understand it that would be appreciated!!

As requested, the XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".GameActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_game">


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile4"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile5"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile6"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/tile8" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile9"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile10"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile11"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile12"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile13"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile14"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="6" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile15"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="7" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile16"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile17"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile18"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile19"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile20"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile21"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tile22"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="6" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile23"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gridLayout" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile24"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile23"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridLayout" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile25"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile24"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gridLayout" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile26"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile25"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile25" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile27"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile26"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tile25" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile28"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile27"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tile25" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile29"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile30"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tile27" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile30"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tile27"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile27" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile31"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile27"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile27" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile32"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile31" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile33"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile29"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile29" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile34"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile29"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile29" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile35"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tile32"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile32" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile36"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile33"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile33" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile37"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tile34"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile34" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile38"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile36"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile35" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile39"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile36"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile38" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile40"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile36"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile39" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile41"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile37"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile36" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile42"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile37"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile41" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile43"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile37"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile42" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile44"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile41"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile37" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile45"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile44"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile37" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile46"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gridLayout" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile47"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tile46"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile28" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile47"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile31" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile49"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile32" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile50"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile35" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile51"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile50" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile52"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile51"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tile39" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile53"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tile51" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile54"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile46"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tile47" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile55"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile52" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile56"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tile45"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile45" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile57"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile47"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile47" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile58"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile49"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile49" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile59"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile50"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile50" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile60"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tile59"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tile52" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile61"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile52"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile52" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile62"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="6"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile55" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tile63"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:layout_column="7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tile55"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tile55" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml.

Comment: It is rather long, since there are over 60 buttons, but I shall.

Comment: Code has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

User `GridLayout` with `layout_columnWeight` in columns and set their `layout_width="0dp"`.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

     <Button
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/tile0"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1" />

     <Button
         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/tile1"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:layout_column="1"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1" />

 ...
```

If you are targeting API level below 14 then you can use `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`.

Comment: Where do I add the "android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout"? Also thank you for the quick response. However, when I add that code, the button simply disappears...

Comment: Add `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'` in to you project elvel build.gradle `dependencies` section.

Comment: Changed the `layout_width="match_parent"`.